# Create order with magento 2 api using credit cart payment method

Tags: magento2, orders, api, payment-methods

I want to create order with Magento 2 API using ***check/money order*** payment method.
I want to save check no. in database it's throwing following error:-

> ordered: string(104) "{"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-58bd682da0738"}"

It's generate error in log file

> api.php

```
<?php 
class MagentoClient 
{   
    public $bearer_token = ''; 
    public $base_url = '';

    public function __construct($token, $base_url)
    {
        $this->base_url = $base_url;
        $this->bearer_token = $token;
    }

    public function request($endpoint, $method = 'GET', $body = FALSE) 
    {

        // Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->base_url . $endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

         $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->bearer_token;
        if ($body) {
          $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
          echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close ($ch);
        return $result;  
     }

     public function getProduct($product_id)
     {
        return $this->request('/products/' . $product_id . '/', 'GET');  
     }

     public function createCart()
    {
        return $this->request('/guest-carts/', 'POST');   
    }

    public function addToCart($cart_id, $product_sku, $quantity = 1)
    {
        $order = array(
            'cartItem' => array(
            'quote_id' => $cart_id,
            'sku' => $product_sku,
            'qty' => $quantity,)
        );
        return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/items',
          'POST',
          json_encode($order)
          );   
    }

    public function setShipping($cart_id, $shipping) 
    {
        return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/shipping-information',
          'POST',
          json_encode($shipping)
        );   
    }

    public function placeOrder($cart_id, $payment_method = 'checkmo',$additional_information='12345') 
    {
        $payment = array(
          'paymentMethod' => array('method' => $payment_method ,'additional_information' => $additional_information)
        ); //var_dump($payment);exit;
        return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/order',
          'PUT',
          json_encode($payment)
        );   
    }

    public function getPaymentMethods($cart_id)
    {
        return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/payment-information', 'GET');  
    }   
} ?>
```

> place-order.php

```
<?php
require_once 'api.php';

// The URL to your Magento 2 instance (ending with /index.php/rest/V1)
$api_url = 'http://192.168.1.100/magento24/index.php/rest/V1';
// Set the integrations access token.
$token = '00qlti27cwtsj2inmjg9w02yve991kib';

// Fill in the SKU of the product which should be ordered.
$sku = 'car';

$magento = new MagentoClient($token, $api_url);

$product = $magento->getProduct($sku);
//echo $product; exit;
$cart = $magento->createCart();
$cart = str_replace('"', '', $cart);

$order_filled = $magento->addToCart($cart, $sku, 1);
//var_dump($order_filled);exit;

$ship_to = array (
  'addressInformation' =>
    array (
      'shippingAddress' =>
        array (
          'region' => 'Wien',
          'region_id' => 95,
          'country_id' => 'AT',
          'street' =>
            array (
              0 => 'Fillgradergasse 12-14/1a',
            ),
          'company' => 'acolono GmbH',
          'telephone' => '1111111',
          'postcode' => '1060',
          'city' => 'Vienna',
          'firstname' => 'Martin',
          'lastname' => 'Testman',
          'email' => 'testman@acolono.com',
          'prefix' => 'address_',
          'region_code' => 'W',
          'sameAsBilling' => 1,
        ),
      'billingAddress' =>
        array (
          'region' => 'Wien',
          'region_id' => 95,
          'country_id' => 'AT',
          'street' =>
            array (
              0 => 'Fillgradergasse 12-14/1a',
            ),
          'company' => 'acolono GmbH',
          'telephone' => '1111111',
          'postcode' => '1060',
          'city' => 'Vienna',
          'firstname' => 'Martin',
          'lastname' => 'Testman',
          'email' => 'testman@acolono.com',
          'prefix' => 'address_',
          'region_code' => 'W',
        ),
      'shipping_method_code' => 'flatrate',
      'shipping_carrier_code' => 'flatrate',
    ),
);

$order_shipment = $magento->setShipping($cart, $ship_to);
// var_dump($order_shipment);

//$payment = $magento->getPaymentMethods($cart);
//var_dump($payment);

$ordered = $magento->placeOrder($cart, 'checkmo', '12345');
echo "\nordered:\n";
var_dump($ordered);
?>
```

Can any one help me on this problem ? Any references or suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance